# `npm install ; npm run build` does not generate build.js on jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, webpack

I have a Jenkins job with a script to run for building a VueJS webapp. The webpack config file has the following:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
```

and the script cleans out old files, pulls in from `git` and then runs:

```
npm install
npm run build
```

If I do this from the unix terminal (as the same user as `jenkins`) then it all works fine - I get a `dist/build.js` file along with the other resources that the config file creates. And `node_modules` has all the deps in there.

However if I do this from a Jenkins job, everything build (`node_modules` etc) except for `build.js` which does not seem to be created. I did a `find` of the entire file system to check if go put elsewhere and the log file does not show anything amiss.

In fact it says the files have been emitted, but to where I don't know...

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim I eventually fixed this; the issue was running directly from jenkins. I instead put the build commands into an .sh script and then called that script from jenkins - then it worked as expected

Comment: Thanks for the response Manish. I've tried what you've told me to do, but it did not work. 
`cd scripts
chmod +x deploy.sh
./deploy.sh`

Comment: `node build/build.js` is stuck every time.

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim OK, sounds like a slightly different issue - build was never stuck in my case, `build.js` just never got produced

Comment: Thanks, Manish. I should post my current issue.